# Database schema design for loan repayment management

Tags: database-design

We have a web-app for tracking periodic payments for a loan, currently we are managing it in a mysql database like this:

`loan_payments` table with the following columns 
`[ id, customerId, installmentNo, installmentAmount, penalty, previousOutstanding, totalReceivable, amountReceived ]`

`receipts` table with the following columns
`[ id, loan_payments.id (FK), paymentAmount, otherPaymentDetails]`

The code flow is as follows:

1. During creation of new Loan, **nrInstallments** rows are entered in the `loan_payments` table for that customer. *Assuming there are fixed 10 installments for all customers, 10 rows will be created*
2. For the first row ( `installmentNo` = 1 ), the `penalty` and `previousOutstanding` will be set to 0.
3. Whenever a new payment is received, the `amountReceived` is incremented by that amount in the **current** installment ( `installmentNo` = 1) and an entry is done in the `payments` table. *At any give time there is only *ONE* current installment*
4. When its time for next installment ( `installmentNo` = 2) , the previous installment's `[ totalReceivable - amountReceived ]` is inserted into the next installment's ( `installmentNo` = 2) `previousOutstanding`. All previous payments/installments are frozen. And intimation is sent to customers indicating, `installmentAmount`, `penalty` and `previousOutstanding` to be paid.
5. Now all payments will be received against this **current** installment (`installmentNo` = 2) and its amountReceived will be incremented whenever a new payment is received.
6. All penalty calculation will be done against the **current** installment.

Currently we do not provide update/delete of any payments that does not belong to the **current** installment.

Everything was working fine, until the client asked for a feature to update/delete previous payments. Following are the problems we will face, if we allow update/delete of previous payments

- Suppose **current** installment no is 5, If user updates payment with installment no 2, all the calculation of `previousOutstanding` and `penalty` will be wrong. This doesnt make sense since, intimations were already sent to customers.
- There are lot of reports currently using the `previousOutstanding` and the `penalty` columns.

Our queries:

1. Is it good design to store `previousOutstanding` and `penalty` in the database? Or should it be calculated in the code?
2. How do we redesign the logic/database to allow the following.

   1. Take payment against *ANY* installmentNo
   2. Allow update/delete of any previous Payment
   3. Flexible penalty calculation. ( Take % from user if required )
   4. Ability to waive off penalty for particular customer for particular installmentNo.
   5. If possible, report showing how much penalty was waived-off for a given customer against which installmentNo. ( If this requirement makes the design complex, we can drop it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An accounting database should be easy to audit, which means it is much better to make it append-only and not edit any old rows. If some columns contain precalculated aggregates, denormalise by dropping them, and put them in a view so your reports still work. The mailings you sent using snapshots of aggregate values should be stored in another append-only table, and since you define these to be snapshots they won't become inaccurate.

Comment: Agreed. I would record modifications as separate records that refer to the same installment. You can adjust outstanding and penalty balances in accordance with the new record.